# Custom Layout in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have created a collection view with custom layout.

The layout method is called when view is loaded. But I want to change the heights with server response. But the method is not getting called again when I use `[CollectionView reloadData];`

How can I call this method for second time ?

```
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling reloadData?

Comment: yes..I mentioned it in question also

Comment: It should be called, you may want to post more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the delegate properly it should call the delegate methods whenever reloading the collectionView `[self.collectionView reloadData]`.

If it is not working try to invalidate the layout

```
 UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [self.collectionView collectionViewLayout];
 [layout invalidateLayout];
 [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:YES];
```